# Send SMS to multiple recipients with curl or Postman

Tags: twilio, notify

I have not been able to send SMS to multiple numbers with Twilio Notify using Postman. Does anyone know a correct syntax for two numbers I could try?

If I enter just one number in the value field for the `ToBinding` parameter it works

```
{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1651000000000"}
```

but if I try entering two numbers like this

```
['{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1651000000000"}',
'{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1651000000000"}']
```

I get the error:

```
{"code": 20001, 
"message": "Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid", 
"more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001", 
"status": 400}
```

Yes, I have seen [How to Send SMS Messages to Multiple Recipients with Twilio Notify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728439/how-to-send-sms-messages-to-multiple-recipients-with-twilio-notify) but it does not answer my question as it is creating an array in a language to passthrough and I just want to do a simple test with Postman.

Comment: Can you try using double-quotes instead of single quotes and escape the inner double quotes using backslash? e.g. 

`["{\"binding_type\":\"sms\", \"address\":\"+1651000000000\"}",
"{\"binding_type\":\"sms\", \"address\":\"+1651000000000\"}"]`

Comment: Thanks Vimanyu, unfortunately it still gave the same error "{"code": 20001, "message": "Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001", "status": 400}"

Answer (score 1):

Here is he cURL syntax:

```
curl -X POST https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS.../Notifications \
--data-urlencode 'ToBinding={"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1407xxxxxx"}' \
--data-urlencode 'ToBinding={"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1802xxxxxx"}' \
-d 'Body=Hello World!' \
-u 'AC...:AUTH_TOKEN' | json_pp
```

For anyone curious, below is Node code for doing same:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('Body', 'Hello from Node-Fetch - IT WORKS!!!');
params.append('ToBinding', '{ "binding_type": "sms", "address": "+1407xxxxxx" }');
params.append('ToBinding', '{ "binding_type": "sms", "address": "+1802xxxxxx" }');

let headers = {Authorization: 'Basic ' + new Buffer.from(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN).toString("base64")};

console.log(`To String Output: ${params.toString()}`);

fetch('https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS.../Notifications',
    {method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: params})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: I believe that the OP was looking to put this in the Postman. From the Twilio docs, `--data-urlencode` parameters would fit as `x-www-form-urlencoded` Body type and `ToBinding` as key. But it'll break when you have multiple `ToBinding` keys. ref: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-test-http-requests-twilio-sms-postman

Comment: Thanks Alan. Good news , even though I was looking for Postman (My fault I did write cURL in the topic) my issue is solved from looking at your cURL example. After seeing in the cURL example that you pass a ToBinding= for each number I tried just adding another ToBinding form field in Postman for the second number and it worked. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly in Postman for sending to multiple numbers (screenshot)
[image: (screenshot)]

In postman under Body > Form-data enter a ToBinding key value pair for each number. In the key field enter "ToBinding" and the value field enter the following syntax for a phone number.

```
{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1651000000000"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We prefer answers that show more than just a link. Pleae [edit] yours.